# In sidewaystable caption, Table 1 and the text are in separate lines

Tags: tables, captions, sidewaystable

In the below LateX code, my problem is that "Table 1" and the caption text ending up in two separate lines. I searched for a solution but found no issue or a solution that was similar. The resulting caption as a figure is below, and what I want it to be "Table 1 Sample table" together in the same line instead of "Table 1" and "Sample table" being in two separate lines. Appreciate any help!

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

    \usepackage{ifpdf}
    \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
    \usepackage{stfloats}
    \usepackage{url}
    
    
    % correct bad hyphenation here
    \hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
    
    % Additional packages
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \title{Bla}
    \maketitle

     Bla bla bla
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{Sample table}
    \label{tab:sample}
      \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Bla1}  & \textbf{Bla2} & \textbf{Bla3}  & \textbf{Bla4}\\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting caption of the Table]

Comment: How does the caption of a regular table as opposed to a sideways table look like?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is the caption style used by the IEEEtran document class, so this is something you should not try to change this if you want to publish with them.

Comment: Oh I see, figures weren't that way so I assumed something was wrong. Thank you @leandriis